# Removing strings from a string vector, from a substring

Tags: c++, string, vector, ucp

I am implementing the unit clause propagation algorithm into c++. I have read in the CNF file to a vector with each clause in individual element of a vector, so for example

```
1 2 0
1 2 3 0
1 0
3 4 0
```

So far I am able to isolate individual elements and set them as a string, so in this example i would set the string to be "1".

The next step would be to remove all elements in the vector which contain a 1, so in this example the 1st, 2nd and 3rd elements would be removed. However when i run the vector remove command

```
clauses.erase(std::remove(clauses.begin(), clauses.end(), "1"), clauses.end());
```

It will only remove elements which are exactly "1", not the elements which contain a 1 as well as other characters. Is there anyway to remove any element of a vector which contains the string?

(I hope this makes sense, thank you for your time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `std::remove_if` and search for a 1 in the string ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75cd9181ce2ab9c3)):

```
clauses.erase(
    std::remove_if(clauses.begin(), clauses.end(), 
        [](const std::string &s) {return s.find('1') != std::string::npos;} 
    ), 
    clauses.end()
);
```

If you don't have C++11 for the lambda, a normal function, or functor, or Boost lambda, or whatever floats your boat, will work as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, I do have one more question, what is the purpose of the []? As It throws up an error in compilation

Comment: @Josh, It introduces the lambda, which is part of C++11, so you'll need to enable C++11 in your compiler (e.g., `-std=c++11`) or choose another option.

Comment: My apologies, I was using an old makefile without the C++11 flag. I have implemented your code in, however it does not seem to be removing anything from the vectors. Also is there any way I can replace the 'i' with a string instead of an int? I have the individual elements assigned to a string called "std::string propagator;" Which i would be using to remove them from the vector. Thank you

Comment: @Josh, I've added a link to a live example in my answer showing that it works. As for your other question, I'm not sure what you're asking? What 'i', and what `int`? Could you perhaps give a better example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: This helps greatly I thank you. Ah I meant 1. In this line "{return s.find('1')" Is there anyway I can replace it with"{return s.find(propagator)". As the string propagator changes throughout the runtime of the program. I hope this makes more sense, and again thank you

Comment: @Josh, Oh, sure, just subbing in `propogator` for `'1'` will make it use the current value of `propogator` as the searched for substring.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much, I did however have to replace the [] with a [&] to get it working. Though I do need to look further into lambdas. You have been a great help, and I can not thank you enough!

Comment: @Josh, Oh, right, I didn't make that connection, sorry. You can't use the enclosing scope's variables unless they are captured.